# Declare a variable of a class without creating an instance of it

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++.

I want to declare a variable without creating an instance of it.

```
MyClass variable;

// More code

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   // More code
   variable = MyClass(0);

   // More code
}
```

If I do that, and `MyClass` only has a constructor declared `MyClass::MyClass(int value)` it fails.

I need to make it global because I'm going to use it on a CallBack function and I can pass that variable as a parameter.

And also, I don't want to create an instance of the class when I declare the variable and then, another instance when I use the constructor. I think I'm wasting resources and CPU time.

Is it possible to declare a variable without instance it?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  Why not just declare the object when you are ready to construct it?

Comment: Because I need it on a CallBack function and I can pass that variable as a parameter.

Comment: If your class is not copyable and not movable, than you can not copy or move it. May be you need two-step initialization with dreaded `init` function? Or maybe `std::optional` could be a... hm... option.

Comment: Maybe I can do `MyClass* variable = NULL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a pointer to delay instantiation. Prefer [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) to raw pointers so you don't have to worry about manual memory management.

```
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<MyClass> variable;

// More code

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   // More code
   variable = std::make_shared<MyClass>(0);

   // More code
}
```

Whether you use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) depends on what you plan to do with the pointer.

Comment: How can we do this with regular pointers ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `std::optional` for this:

```
#include <optional>

std::optional<MyClass> variable; // not initialized

int main() {
    if (variable) {
        // enters this if only when initialized
    }

    variable = MyClass(0);

    // Access the contained value:
    MyClass value = *variable;
    int member = variable->member;
}
```

The `std::optional` type is available in C++17. If your project is constrained to an older version, you can always use a [polyfill](https://github.com/tcbrindle/cpp17_headers)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but it seems like you have created a constructor like :

```
MyClass(int v) : value(v) {}
```

and not written the default constructor, which may look like :

```
MyClass() {}
```

Because of this, the compiler cannot find the constructor to instantiate a MyClass object when you write:

```
MyClass variable;
```

In short, you have to explicitly write the default constructor when you have written other constructors but also want to use the default one.

And your question is a bit vague, when you declare a variable of a class like above, you are indeed creating an instance of it. Even when doing

```
variable = MyClass(0);
```

you are creating a temporary object of MyClass and then using the assignment operator to assign it to the *variable* object.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to create an instance when I declare it and then another instance when I use the constructor.

Comment: Yes, I think that a smart pointer is a solution then, as suggested by John.

Answer (score 1):

You could just initialise the variable with some temporary value with the existing constructor when you declare it. Ideally with a value you could easily identify when debugging.

```
MyClass variable(-1);
```

Although then it would probably make more sense to just add a default constructor that does that.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to declare a variable without creating an instance of it.

In your code you have:

> ```
> MyClass variable;
> ```

Declared in the global namespace. Here variable is still an instance of MyClass; it just has different storage, linkage and lifetime than if it was within a function.

As to having it declared in a global namespace and initializing it afterwards
here is what I have tried this and it seems to work for me. I'm not sure if this is what you are after, but I think this may work for you.

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
private:
    int value_;

public:
    MyClass() : value_{ 0 } {}
    explicit MyClass(int value) : value_{ value } {}

    MyClass& operator()(int value) {
        value_ = value;
        return *this;
    }

    int value() const { return value_; }
};

MyClass myClass;

int main() {
    std::cout << myClass.value() << '\n';

    myClass = MyClass(2) << '\n';
    std::cout << myClass.value() << '\n';

    myClass(5);
    std::cout << myClass.value() << '\n';

    std::cout << myClass(8).value() << '\n';        

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
0
2
5
8
```

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to create an instance of the class when I declare the variable and then, another instance when I use the constructor. I think I'm wasting resources and CPU time.